# ASP.Net form authentication and IIS throws 404 error for a protected page from Google app iPhone request but public page displayed correctly

Tags: ios, .net, iis

Our application is Identity provider and enabled sp init sso for a google iphone mobile application. We are using .Net form authentication , IIS 7.5. This flwo works perfectly across all devices and platforms and also works iwth iphone PagerDuty mobile app. The only problem is with iphone google doc mobile app. When SP init sso initiated from google doc iphone mobile app, IIS throws 404 error page for protected pages but public page displayed correctly. I spent many days with google search and tried out most of the solutions available but none of them helped to resolve thsi issue. now client needs to execute this flow daily but no solution.

Below are few things from many things I tried.

```
1)    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

2)    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"  type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      <!-- any other modules you want to run in MVC e.g. FormsAuthentication,       Roles etc. -->
      </modules> 

     <system.webServer>

3)    In IIS select your website and double-click Handler Mappings
      Find ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit and double-click
      In the dialog that appears, click Request Restrictions
      On the Verbs tab add the missing HTTP verbs separated by commas (in my    case it was PUT and DELETE
      Click Ok where required and answer Yes in the Edit Script Map dialog that pops up.
      Repeat for ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit
      <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      </modules>
      </system.webServer>



  4) <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <remove verb="OPTIONS" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>



   5) IIS Manager > Modules > select UrlRoutingModule-4.0 > Edit Module >     check the check-box "Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers".

6)  <security>
      <requestFiltering>
          <verbs applyToWebDAV="true">
              <remove verb="PUT" />
              <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
              <remove verb="DELETE" />
              <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
              <remove verb="PATCH" />
              <add verb="PATCH" allowed="true" />
          </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solutions in below link. in case helpful to any one. Thanks.

https://forums.asp.net/p/2115947/6118514.aspx?Re+ASP+Net+form+authentication+and+IIS+throws+404+error+for+a+protected+page+from+Google+app+iPhone+request+but+public+page+displayed+correctly